# jQuery radio check hitting wrong statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Morning (for some),

I'm attempting to get the value of a set of radio buttons and then, using an if statement, target the value of the radio that is checked.

This is the HTML for the radio buttons.

```
<input type="radio" class="radio_search" name="sport" value="yes">Yes
<input type="radio" class="radio_search" name="sport" value="no">No
```

And then this is the jQuery code.

```
$(function(){

    $('.radio_search').change(function(){

        var radio = $('.radio_search:checked').val();
        if(radio = "yes"){
            alert("yes");
        }
        else if(radio = "no"){
            alert("no");
        }
    });
});
```

The issue is that, regardless of the selection, "yes" is always displayed.

Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: `=` is not the same as `==` - `radio == "yes"`

Comment: And == is not the same as ===

Comment: What a ridiculous error, my word! Does anyone fancy answering it or shall I just delete it?

Comment: @Luke better delete it... as it does not add any value to future users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=` is an assignement, `==` is for testing equality

```
$(function(){

  $('.radio_search').change(function(){

      var radio = $('.radio_search:checked').val();
      if(radio == "yes"){
          alert("yes");
      }
      else if(radio == "no"){
          alert("no");
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){

    $('.radio_search').change(function(){

        var radio ==$('.radio_search:checked').val();
        if(radio == "yes"){ // == instead of assign = operator
            alert("yes");
        }
        else if(radio == "no"){ // == instead of assign = operator
            alert("no");
        }
    });
});
```